# Kotlin ListOf Objects

Tags: list, object, kotlin

I want to create a ListOf Objects of a Class in Kotlin.
For example I want to create 10 Objekts (Objekt1, Objekt2...Objekt10) using a “for“ loop where the number of Objekts is variable.
Can someone help me?
Example:

```
val listOfAnimals = mutableListOf<Tier>()
for (document in result) {
var tierObject  : Tier = Tier("","")
tierObject.name="${document.getString("Name")}"
tierObject.fotos="${document.getString("Fotos")}"
listOfAnimals.add(tierObject)
}
```

But with this I got a listOfAnimals with the correct number of objects but the object (and his properties) are Always the same because the object Name (tierObject) is always the same.
==> Today I tried my Example again and now it works fine...I don't know why but it works :-)

Comment: `List(10) { n -> ... }` where you replace `...` with the code to initialize "Objekt" n. If this is not what you meant, provide an example of what you're trying to achive and what you already tried.

Comment: Thank you...I tried somethinh like this:
val listOfAnimals = mutableListOf<Tier>()
for (document in result) {
var tierObject  : Tier = Tier("","")
tierObject.name="${document.getString("Name")}"
tierObject.fotos="${document.getString("Fotos")}"
listOfAnimals.add(tierObject)
}
But with this I got a listOfAnimals with the correct number of objects but the object (and his properties) are Always the same because the object Name (tierObject) is Always the same.